# Web part to list all pages unless they are hidden (site settings -> navigation)?

Tags: web-part, navigation

I have a web part that displays all pages in a repeater from the current site. If I go to site settings -> navigation and hide one of the pages then I don't want this page to be displayed in the web part. Is this a property for the page or in the navigation (Navigation.TopNavigationBar)?

Answer (score 0):

I think that translates to `PortalSiteMapNode.IsVisible` property. So if you are displaying the pages using `PortalSiteMapProvider` as underlying data source, the page should be not be visible.

Comment: Unfortunately IsVisible is always set to true even if the page is hidden.